# What is wrong with my command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to do a 1 person sleep command in my realms, and my code won't work for one specific line:

```
execute if entity @a[scores={KickBed=1..,}] run execute if score @a[scores={sleep=1..,}] run tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"selector":"@p[scores={KickBed=1,}]","color":"white"},{"text":" doesn't want to skip the night!","color":"red"}]}
```

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/eim04i/oneplayer_sleeping_for_115x_minecraft_pc_command/?sort=top) is where I got the command from. All the code after the “run” in the code turned red after I entered it into command blocks.

Comment: The particular part of that line of code where it goes wrong is this part:
{sleep=1..,}] run tellraw @ a {"text":"","extra"


**You need to ignore the spaces after the @ sign because the reddit post was formatted like that. I removed them in my real code

Comment: I didn’t receive an error message it just messed up right after the “run” in the code on my comment. The remained for the line of code was red

Answer (score 2):

I know what the problem is!

```
execute
  if entity @a[scores={KickBed=1..}]
  if score @a[scores={sleep=1..}]
run tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"selector":"@p[scores={KickBed=1,}]","color":"white"},{"text":" doesn't want to skip the night!","color":"red"}]}
```

The mistake is that the second `if score` argument needs to be `if entity`.

Fixed command:

```
execute if entity @a[scores={KickBed=1..}] if entity @a[scores={sleep=1..}] run tellraw @a {"text":"","extra":[{"selector":"@p[scores={KickBed=1,}]","color":"white"},{"text":" doesn't want to skip the night!","color":"red"}]}
```